# Resize UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, resize

I need to resize `UITableView` without having scroll bar for tableView inside `UIScrollView`. I am adding `UITableVieCell` dynamically in that table view. After adding values, table should resize. It contains a scroll bar. I don't need scroll bar, I need to show everything. And also there are some text fields and labels below that particular table.

Comment: Not exactly what do you do. but have a tableview within a scrollview is a `bad practice`. With this course, you can check if you are using `constraints` and try to move the table using the `constant`

Comment: I am new to objective c language and iso. Is there any way to fullfil my requirements which is able to add dynamic values or cells and able to handle tap event